# Regarding WCF InstanceContextMode

Tags: wcf

i am very new in WCF. so often gaze for wcf code & article. after viewing many code i often stuck for very basic things and got no elaborate discussion for the below question. so here are my few basic question....and looking for details discussion with sample situation and with sample code.

what is InstanceContextMode? 
many people use InstanceContextMode Single or PerCall or PerSession ?

i just need deep insight when i should go for InstanceContextMode Single or or PerCall or PerSession ? what it does basically ??

tell me briefly when i woul turn on Single what will happen or what will happen in case of PerCall or PerSession ? what is difference between Single or PerCall or PerSession

what is default InstanceContextMode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) property indicates how WCF will create instances of your service class and whether those instances will be reused across requests.

- **PerSession**: (the default) an instance of your service will be created for each WCF session, for channels that support sessions (otherwise, the behavior is the same as PerCall); this value is useful if you maintain state within your service class for each client session
- **PerCall**: a new instance of your service class will be created for each WCF operation (method call) from the client
- **Single**: only a single service instance will be created within the host process, which will service all incoming requests; all calls will be serialized to the service unless the service's [ConcurrencyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx) behavior is set to `Multiple`.

For high-volume stateless services, using `Single` and `ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` can reduce the number of service instances allocated and the associated pressure on the garbage collector. WCF doesn't require/assume that your service is stateless, though, which is why `PerSession` is the default.

You can verify the behavior of the different instance context modes by setting a breakpoint in your service's default constructor.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. i am not good in wcf and just learning it. so please guide me how can i debug the wcf service just to understand better the InstanceContexMode. can u write simple code which i can debug and understand the behaviour of InstanceContexMode debug in step-by-step. thanks

Comment: I have a WCF extensions library with lots of samples [here](https://github.com/bspell1/wcfex). If you pull down the code, there is an in-process sample that should allow you to set breakpoints in a WCF service. The sample is under Samples/InProc/ConsoleEcho/Client. The service is in MockOutput.cs, to which you should be able to add the ServiceBehavior attribute and set a breakpoint in.

Comment: what r u trying to say InProc??

Comment: It's short for in-process. It means hosting the WCF service within the same process as the client application.

Comment: Correct, but it's more than that. The in-process transport is more efficient than simply self-hosting a WCF service over another transport (such as TCP), because there is no encoding or message serialization overhead.

Comment: I believe PerCall is the default now.